# What are the solutions to the inequality $|x|(ax+1)<2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Solve absolute value inequalities depending on the parameter $a$.

$$|x|(ax+1)<2$$
In the first case where we have $x>0,\;a>0$  we get: 
$$ax^2+x-2<0$$ I get that $x$ is in the interval $\left(0,-\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8a}}{2a}\right)$?

Comment: If $x>0$, then $|x|=x$ and if $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$. If $x=0$ the inequality holds.

Comment: it is not so simple, you must solve the whole inequality

Comment: In both case a can be >,< or =0.Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to solve $$x>0$$ and $$ax^2+x-2<0$$ or $$x<0$$ and $$-ax^2-x-2<0$$

Comment: In first case $$a*x^2+x-2<0$$ , x>0,a>0 i get that  x is from interval (0,$$(-1+\sqrt{1+8*a})/2*a)$$)